# How would you mathematically pose the problem of dividing people into nations?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

There are parts of nations within which many people want to become independent from the parent nation. Other nations think certain parts of other nations should be part of their territory instead. I am wondering if there is any mathematics about (re)drawing the borders of nations, based on the connections (same language, same ...) between people. Maybe this can be formulated as a problem in graph theory?

If the previous paragraph is not specific enough, then my question is: **How would you mathematically pose the problem of dividing people into nations?**

Comment: What about having only one nation called Humanity on Earth? That makes the mathematical problem simple.

Comment: Why borders? Why can't two (or more) nations share the governance of a region? Let each person choose the nation he/she wants to be part of.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, that seems not to be how reality works out for the moment. But I suppose you could reframe the question to optimal division into provinces in that case.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, nations sharing the governance of a region is possible and interesting, but does not seem to be how reality works out (most of the time?). Secondly, how would you determine the list of countries people can choose between?

Comment: @hkBst Interesting point in your comment is *optimal division*. Good luck however to define the function to optimize! This won't be a mathematical question but a political one.